# Baking an MC on a hotplate with magnetic stir

Tags: magnet

I recently got a batch of MCs (ESP32s) [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/891/esp32_wroom_32e_esp32_wroom_32ue_datasheet_en-1855879.pdf) that were not in a desiccated and sealed bag.  Because they are humidity sensitive devices and I am reflow soldering I needed to bake them to ensure that the module wasn't damaged during soldering.

I placed the ESPs on a hotplate which I verified to be 105C for 24hrs.  This hotplate, like most, has an option for stirring which uses a magnetic field to rotate a stir bar on the plate's surface.  I turned the magnetic stirring knob to 0 but noticed that if I placed a allen wrench on the surface, it was pulled slightly to the center of the plate.  So there must've still been some magnetic field present when I placed the ESPs onto the hotplate for baking.

Is it likely that this magnetic field damaged my ESPs during the 24hr baking process?

Comment: Do you think that a static magnetic field can destroy ICs? Are they actually destroyed?

Comment: Damaged is probably a better word, I will edit the question.

Comment: Are they (or some of them) actually damaged? If so, where did you buy them from?

Comment: I don't know if they are damaged, I have a dev board I am working on with the first chip from the batch and am experiencing a problem.  And I started to wonder about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hot plate with a magnetic stirrer uses a permanent magnet. The knob simply adjusts the speed of the motor.

There is not a magnetic storage system in the ESP32 so no chance of damage to data storage.

There is no buck or boost converter on the chip so there is no inductor that could generate a current from your oscillating magnetic field.

I think you'll be fine.

Comment: Any loop can generate a current from a changing magnetic field, but you usually need many turns to make anything significant, but anyway, the magnetic field was not oscillating.

Comment: Thank you for your "technically correct" but essentially-impossible-to-have-a-meaningful-effect-in-reallife clarification.